# ERROR: Cannot open PostgreSQL DB connection

Tags: postgresql, docker, coturn

While connecting to the external PostgreSQL database, installed in my Windows 11 machine, through docker I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot open PostgreSQL DB connection: <host=192.168.31.173>, runtime error
```

I'm using this command :

```
docker run -d -p 3478:3478 -p 3478:3478/udp -p 5349:5349 -p 5349:5349/udp -p 49160-49200:49160-49200/udp coturn/coturn -n --log-file=stdout --external-ip='$(detect-external-ip)' --min-port=49160 --max-port=49200 -e, --psql-userdb="host=192.168.31.173 port=5432 dbname=webrtc connect_timeout=10"
```

In C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data\pg_hba.conf, I have give permission to my IP:

```
host      all      all      192.168.31.173/16      trust
```

[image]

Comment: What is the rest of the error message?

Comment: @jjanes this is the only error I'm getting in coturn turn server logs

Comment: Can you see anything in the PostgreSQL log file?

Comment: @jjanes there is no logs regarding this in PostgreSQL logs, because database is not reachable, but same connection is working through .net c# code. There is a communication issue between docker and  external PostgreSQL.